# Eslint prop missing validation with Formik

Tags: reactjs, eslint, formik

I am using Formik in my project and now I have started using Eslint. I am getting a bunch of messages saying stuff like for example, "values is missing in props validation" or "errors is missing in props validation".

These are Formik props and I would have thought I do not need to validate them manually.

Any idea how to get rid of those lint errors?

Comment: Can you please try defining propTypes through [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and check ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have already tried that, the problem is that if I do PropTypes.array or PropTypes.object then I get another ESLint error (e.g. "Prop type array is forbidden").

Comment: For that error, PropTypes.instanceOf(Array) this should work.

Comment: Thanks Krina, I have tried and it removes that error but at the end of the story I still get "PropType is defined but never used". I think this is because I am specifying PropTypes for my functional component props. However, the "real" used props come from Formik through render props. That again makes me think it should be Formik the one checking that internally...